# Why is the Java OpenCV module unavailable according to Cmake?

Tags: java, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to use Cmake to bind OpenCV to java but whenever I try to configure it the output says that the OpenCV java module is unavailable in this message:

```
OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann fuzzy hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto       
    Disabled:                    js python_bindings_generator world  
    Disabled by dependency: cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv freetype hdf **java** matlab ovis python2 python3 sfm viz      -
```

.

I'm using Java 1.8.0_181 and MinGW version x86_64-posix-seh, and OpenCV and OpenCV Contrib 4.0.0

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should definitely provide more info about the problem, including the error message you got, where you have java installed and so.

Comment: Thank you, would this be better?

Comment: Yes, now it is much better.